# HDI: Dim the screen beyond the typical maximum?

Tags: linux, xorg, display-settings

I'm on a Dell Latitude E6320, and the screen doesn't get very dim.  It's way too bright even when it's dimmed as far as Ubuntu will let it.  How do I dim it more?

For example, when you have this problem on a windows system, you can install a program like Dimmer (http://www.mylittlehost.com/dimmer.aspx) that overlays a black over your whole display (and you can configure the opacity, allowing you to dim the screen beyond the normal max).  Is there any way to deal with a too-bright screen in linux?"

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface /sys/class/backlight has this. I.e.

```
echo 4000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Other interesting values are:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
4648
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness
4000
```

Please note, pr. default, these are writeable by root only.

Comment: You can use `setpci` to change these values as a normal user. The syntax is more cryptic though. For my system this is `setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=XX` where XX is a hex value between 00 and ff. The device (after the -s) can be found out with 'ls -l /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight' where I see `devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0` in the device path.

Comment: Oh and be careful in either case with 0 as display brightness. I have a Pixel Qi display and I will see something with the backlight switched off completely (and I searched long for a way to accomplish this) but you most likely won't see much so have a reverting line in your bash history where you can find it blindly.